# voice mail (VVM) in android

Tags: android, audio-recording, voicemail

I am trying to develop an android application which will retrieve a voicemail message left by a user, but I'm stuck in its development
because  resources on Internet are quite limited about voicemail.
I haven t had any problems in my application to retrieve a sms but for
voicemail,  it s another thing ....

I would advice in order to guide me because I am a bit lost

Thanks

Comment: hi did you got solution for get voicemail left by user.. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voicemails are typically stored (in North America at least) on the carrier's voicemail system, which generally don't have standard, published programming interfaces for retrieving any data (I'm assuming they have SOME programming interface).

So not sure what you want is trivially possible.

Answer (score 1):

Visual voicemail requires a whole layer of carrier support that you're not going to find. If you *do* have carrier support then it's the carrier's burden to enlighten you as to the specifications for accessing it.

Voicemail isn't contained on the device as SMS messages are, so there's no analogous API.